# How can i fix the error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00:20' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS 'Customer_Name',
    Contact_Number, date_time, summary, OtherDetails, Duration
FROM 
    Support_Call AS sc 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    customer AS c ON sc.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE 
    Call_Status = 'Unresolved' AND Duration >= '00:20'
ORDER BY 
    Duration DESC;
```

How can I fix this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00:20' to data type int.

Comment: What is the column type of `Duration`?

Comment: Column type of duration is int

Comment: If it's storing minutes, then just use `Duration >= 20`.

Comment: How do you think you can convert `:` to `INT`?

Comment: What's the type of `duration`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Tim in the comments, if `Duration` is an `int` column as the error suggests (and stores a number of minutes), then you need:

```
SELECT 
    First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS 'Customer_Name',
    Contact_Number, 
    date_time, 
    summary, 
    OtherDetails, 
    Duration
FROM Support_Call AS sc 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN customer AS c ON sc.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE Call_Status = 'Unresolved' 
AND Duration >= 20
ORDER BY Duration DESC;
```

The value `'00:20'` in your original query is not an `int` value and cannot be implicitly converted to one (whereas a `varchar` value of `'128'` for example could be).